# Old and new storage compatibility ink!::env::set_code_hash()

Tags: ink

Based on the note about storage compatibility https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/fn.set_code_hash.html:

`The storage at the code hash will remain untouched. This means that contract developers must ensure that the storage layout of the new code is compatible with that of the old code.`

My question is:

1. How exactly storage compatibility is defined? There are rules for upgrading a contract with openzeppelin https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/writing-upgradeable#modifying-your-contracts. Do the exactly same rules apply for this `set_code_hash`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How exactly storage compatibility is defined? There are rules for upgrading a contract with openzeppelin https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/writing-upgradeable#modifying-your-contracts. Do the exactly same rules apply for this `set_code_hash`

It's exactly as described in the docs which you linked.

I've created a GitHub issue for us to document this better. Thanks for bringing this up, our documentation is written by us core developers and it's sometimes hard to see those non-obvious things.

Comment: Yes this is perfect.